# "Edge slide" for bones?

Tags: bones

I have a number of bones which deform segments of the eyelash + eye skin which all radiate from a single point in XYZ space (aka the center of the eye-sphere) to various Snapped (to vertex) positions along the eye skin, like so. I want to put the heads where the tails currently are; this can be by flipping the bone around (so the tail goes where the head was; may require roll and/or driver adjustment) or sliding along the shaft (so that the tail protrudes past the eye into space). I can't scale since the heads are all at the same XYZ position and scaling from the center of all the bone tails would give a poor result. **Is there a way for me to "edge slide" the heads along each bone shaft?** Thanks!

EDIT: Am dumb and found out how to flip the head and tail designation of a bone shortly after asking (Edit -> Armature -> Switch Direction, aka <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). The "edge slide for bones" question still stands, in cases where one might not want the new head position exactly at the tail position.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to "edge slide" the heads along each bone shaft?

Yes.  Each bone's head and tail lie in a particular axis for that bone-- the Y axis.  So if you select a head and move it in that axis, you'll be edge sliding the head along the bone.

Switch to normal orientation, individual origins pivot.  (In edit mode, normal orientation will use each bone's local axes for the transform, while local orientation will use the armature's local axes.)  Select as many heads or tails as you want.  Translate constrained to Y axis (g Y move mouse confirm for me).

Answer (score 1):

Select one bone head and press Shift S - Cursor to selected. Switch the pivot point to cursor in the 3D view drop down menu, select the bones and scale them.

[image]